# redux-observable - difference between concat vs concatMap

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I am trying to wrap my head around the difference between **concat** and **concatMap** when using **redux-observable**.

In my intuition, I'm thinking that concatMap would work:
- From a `FAKE_LOGIN` action, it will be switchMap-ed to emit `FAKE_LOGIN_AUTHENTICATING` action.
- Inside a `FAKE_LOGIN_AUTHENTICATING` action, it will be concatMap-ed to emit `FAKE_LOGIN_SUCCESS` action, after a delay of 2 seconds.

However, the above thinking does not work. I tried all sorts of combinations and finally chanced upon the concat operator and surprisingly it works.

What is the difference between the two?

Below are my codes:

this *does not* work

```
action$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    action => of( { type: 'FAKE_LOGIN_AUTHENTICATING' } ).pipe(
      concatMap( thing => {
        return of( { type: 'FAKE_LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: { userId: 'user-a', userData: {} } } ).pipe(
          delay( 2000 )
        );
      } )
    )
  )
);
```

But this does

```
action$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    action => of( { type: 'FAKE_LOGIN_AUTHENTICATING' } ).pipe(
      concat(
        of( { type: 'FAKE_LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: { userId: 'user-a', userData: {} } } ).pipe(
          delay( 2000 )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I don't understand your use-case exactly but the main difference between `concatMap` and `concat` is that `concatMap` accepts as a parameter a function that is invoked for every item from its source and that returns an inner Observable (it maps each item from its source to an Observable). `concatMap` then calls its callback only when the previous inner Observables completes.

On the other hand, `concat` just accepts a list of Observables and subscribes to them one after another when the previous Observable completes.

So in your case the first example just "maps" `FAKE_LOGIN_AUTHENTICATING` to `FAKE_LOGIN_SUCCESS`.

In the second example the inner block is equivalent to this:

```
concat(
  of({ type: 'FAKE_LOGIN_AUTHENTICATING' }),
  of({ type: 'FAKE_LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: { userId: 'user-a', userData: {}}}).pipe(
    delay(2000),
  )
)
```

So it first subscribes to `of({ type: 'FAKE_LOGIN_AUTHENTICATING' })` that emits and completes immediately, then subscribes to `of({ type: 'FAKE_LOGIN_SUCCESS'...)` that emits immediately as well and then completes.